# Rails simple_form_for update action routing error [POST] with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, patch, put, simple-form-for

I try to update customer object via simple_form_for with Rails 6

From `show.html.erb` I have `<%= render partial: "form", object: @customer, as: 'customer' %>`

My form example: `_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for customer, remote: true, url: customer_path(customer), method: :patch do |f| %>
```

I don't know why, Rails throw RoutingError

`ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/customers/1"):`

My routing:

```
resources :customers, only: %i[show create new update]
```

Comment: Remove `url: customer_path(customer)` and `method: :patch`

Comment: Nope, still have POST

Comment: What do your `new` and `edit` views look like?

Comment: There is no `new.html.rb` or `edit.html.erb`. From action `show` my form is render through partial `_form.html.erb`. My request parameters have `_method"=>"patch"` but I end up with RoutingError [POST]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`config.api_only = false` allow Middleware to `Rack::MethodOverride`

I have `config.api_only = true` and that's was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, no need to specify the method, because rails enough smart to identify whether the object is new or persisted. And check your routes as well.

<%= simple_form_for customer, remote: true do |f| %>

Comment: Nope, still have POST

Answer (score 0):

You can use edit partial and remove the parameters `url: customer_path(customer) and method: :patch`. And simple form for automatically send request put path

Comment: I try to change `_form.html.erb` to  `_edit.html.erb` but, still have POST.